# How to make Post Request from Controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, http-post

I have 2 server, I want when I upload image to server 1 (S1), this image will be upload to server 2 (S2). So i think i need make a POST request from Controller on S1.

For upload image to another server: i have tried some way as curl, guzzle with no success.

Please let me know how to make a POST request.

Comment: You need a POST route in S2 and use it in S1 as the action of the form. Did you try something like this?

Comment: "i have tried some way as curl, guzzle with no success" It should work, so what do you mean by "no success"? More about guzzle here; http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=upload#uploading-data